# iOS Keyboard Delaying Animations

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitextview, uitoolbar

I'm currently trying to develop a chat feature for an iOS app. I've been playing around with the keyboard and everything seems to be working other than the animation.

When I press the keyboard the animation to move the view up is delayed by a second. I've made a [video of it happening here](https://gfycat.com/HotNiftyGalapagosalbatross).

My code is as follows:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
```

The selectors:

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow: (NSNotification *) notif{
    NSDictionary *info = [notif userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    _currentKeyboardHeight = kbSize.height;

    // Calculate free space between navigation bar and keyboard top to reposition the chat bubbles.
    float areaHeight = screenHeight - (_currentKeyboardHeight + _footer.frame.size.height + 100);

    if([Infrastructure_Connection ConnectivityCheck]){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
            [_ChatBar setFrame:CGRectMake(posX, screenHeight-(_currentKeyboardHeight+height), width, height)];
            bubbleTableMain.frame = CGRectMake(0,100, self.view.frame.size.width,areaHeight);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [bubbleTableMain scrollBubbleViewToBottomAnimated:YES];
        }];
    } else {
    [RegisterUser AlertMessage:@"Offline" Message:@"You're currently in offline mode."];
    }
}


- (void)keyboardDidHide: (NSNotification *) notif{
    int whereKeyboardEnds = self.view.frame.size.height-(195);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.0 options:0 animations:^{
        bubbleTableMain.frame = CGRectMake(0,100, self.view.frame.size.width,whereKeyboardEnds);
        [_ChatBar setFrame:CGRectMake(posX, 474, width, height)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) { }];
}
```

The delays are on 0.0 and still it delays it by a second. Anyone have any idea as to how, for example, Whatsapp make their keyboard interaction so smooth and in time with the keyboard appearing?

=================== Edit ===================

So I've changed the following code and now for some reason, it doesn't run the animation. I've debugged it and it calls the selector correctly. But doesn't animate:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

and

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve = [[[note userInfo] valueForKey: UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [[[note userInfo] valueForKey: UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:animationCurve];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    [_ChatBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, _ChatBar.frame.size.width, _ChatBar.frame.size.height)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the keyboardDidShow notification  which is called after the keyboard has finished its animation. Use the keyboardWillShow notification instead. That should do the trick.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! I've changed the call and updated the method. However now the animation doesn't run? In debug it runs through the method but doesn't execute the animation. I've edited my original question to show the updated code. It works with the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification but not with the UIKeyboardWillShowNotification. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the values of animationCurve and animationDuration?